# How to debug init.d script that isn't being run

Tags: debian, init.d

I am trying to get `god` to start during boot on Debian. I added a script to the `/etc/init.d/` directory which looks like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          god
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog 
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: start god process monitoring
# Description:       Start god process monitoring
### END INIT INFO

god_conf="absolute/path/to/god.conf"
god_pid_file="/var/run/god/god.pid" ; mkdir -p `dirname $god_pid_file`
god_log_file="/var/log/god/god.log" ; mkdir -p `dirname $god_log_file`
case "$1" in
  start)
    god -c "$god_conf" -P "$god_pid_file" -l "$god_log_file"
    RETVAL=$?
    echo "God started"
    ;;
...
```

I ran the following command to create the necessary symbolic links `sudo update-rc.d god defaults`

However, when I reboot the machine, god does not seem to get started. My question is, how can I debug this problem?

I have looked at `dmesg` and don't see anything related to `god`. I have also looked at the `syslog` and didn't see anything there. Also, the `god.log` file is empty and there is no `god.pid` file.

I don't know if the problem is that my init script is not even getting called or if it is failing when it tries to start god. I have tried starting god manually by running `sudo /etc/init.d/god start` and that seems to work fine. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd start by adding `exec > /var/log/god/initlog 2>&1` as the first statement after the `mkdir`s, so you can see exactly what's going on.

Comment: Post the complete script, and the output of `ls -l /etc/rc.d/*god`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I don't think the script is even getting run. The directories for the log and pid files don't even exist after a reboot so it must not even be getting to the `mkdir`s

Comment: @Gilles I tried running `ls -l /etc/rc.d/*god` and get an error saying `cannot access /etc/rc.d/*god: No such file or directory`. Withink /etc/ there is no rc.d directory, however it does have the following directories `rc0.d/ rc1.d/ rc2.d/ rc3.d/ rc4.d/ rc5.d/ rc6.d/ rcS.d/`

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant `ls -l /etc/rc?.d/*god` — but in fact your problem is presumably the bad shebang line that I spotted afterwards.

Comment: `pi@raspberrypi /var/log $ ls -l /etc/rc0.d/*god
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr 12 18:17 /etc/rc0.d/K01god -> ../init.d/god`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/sh
> ```

The normal location of `sh`, in almost every unix out there, is `/bin/sh`. Some unix variants have merged `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, so `/usr/bin/sh` also works, but the portable way is `/bin/sh`, so that's what you should use in shebangs. Most importantly for you, on Debian, unless you've gone out of your way, there is no `/usr/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather then attempt to roll my own I'd make use of this version I found via google.

- [gistfile1.sh](https://gist.github.com/donnoman/1643445)

*excerpt*

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          god
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: God initscript
### END INIT INFO

# This is a Generated Init Script see the source: https://github.com/donnoman/cap-recipes/blob/master/lib/cap_recipes/tasks/god/god.init

# Author: Johnny Domino (domino@cmu.edu)
# Adapted: Donovan Bray (donnoman@donovanbray.com)

# PATH should only include /usr/* if it runs after the mountnfs.sh script
PATH="/custom/ree/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
DESC="God Monitoring Tool"
NAME=god
CONF=/var/www/application/current/config/daemons.god
LEVEL=info
LOGFILE="/var/www/application/shared/log/god.log" ; mkdir -p `dirname $LOGFILE`
PIDFILE="/var/www/application/shared/pids/god.pid" ; mkdir -p `dirname $PIDFILE`
DAEMON=/var/www/application/current/bin/god
DAEMON_ARGS="-c $CONF -P $PIDFILE --log-level $LEVEL --log $LOGFILE"
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/god
OPEN_SOCKET=yes
USE_TERMINATE_ON_KILL=yes

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6) to ensure that this file is present.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been started
    #   1 if daemon was already running
    #   2 if daemon could not be started
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
        || return 1
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- \
        $DAEMON_ARGS \
        || return 2
    # Add code here, if necessary, that waits for the process to be ready
    # to handle requests from services started subsequently which depend
    # on this one.  As a last resort, sleep for some time.
    [ "$OPEN_SOCKET" != no ] && sleep 3 && sh -c "chmod 0777 /tmp/god.*.sock;true"
}

# kills god + everything god is monitoring
do_terminate()
{
    $DAEMON terminate
    RETVAL="$?"
    return "$RETVAL"
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
    $DAEMON quit
    RETVAL="$?"
    return "$RETVAL"
}

#
# Function that sends a SIGHUP to the daemon/service
#
do_reload() {
    #
    # If the daemon can reload its configuration without
    # restarting (for example, when it is sent a SIGHUP),
    # then implement that here.
    #
    log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC" "$NAME"
    $DAEMON load $CONF
    return 0
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_start
    case "$?" in
        0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  stop)
    if [ "$0" != "$SCRIPTNAME" ] && [ "$USE_TERMINATE_ON_KILL" = "yes" ]; then
      [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Terminating $DESC" "$NAME"
      do_terminate
    else
      [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
      do_stop
    fi
    case "$?" in
        0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  terminate)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Terminating $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_terminate
    case "$?" in
            0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
            2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  status)
    $DAEMON status && exit 0 || exit $?
    status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
    ;;
  reload|force-reload)
    do_reload
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;
  restart)
    #
    # If the "reload" option is implemented then remove the
    # 'force-reload' alias
    #
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
      0|1)
        do_start
        case "$?" in
            0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
            1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
            *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
        esac
        ;;
      *)
        # Failed to stop
        log_end_msg 1
        ;;
    esac
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart|terminate|force-reload}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac
```